# JavaScript: How to close all child windows upon user opt logoff?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Requirement:**

1. All child windows which are opened and they are required to remain
   open through out the user session on IE  irrespective of user action
   refreshes the browser windows.
2. Close all child windows when user click logoff action.

**Problem:**

Child window handle cannot be retained across the pages when browser re-render the window, due to F5/refresh button or navigation.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

1. Open each child window with identical name.
2. Save the assigned window name in local storage as item in collection or array [or in parent window.name that's the work around if local storage is not acceptable].

```js
//Open popup window "ChildWinName1" from here
window.open("SomeSite/SomeApp/SomePage", "ChildWinName1", "width=600, height=400");
localStorage.setItem("Key1", "ChildWinName1");

//Open popup window "ChildWinName1" from here
window.open("SomeSite/SomeApp/SomePage", "ChildWinName2", "width=600, height=400");
localStorage.setItem("Key2", "ChildWinName2");
```

3. Create a blank page in your application which just has self.close method in script.

Page : BlankClose

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>IndexX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Exit() {
            self.close();
        }
        this.Exit();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Bye..............
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Upon logoff, iterate through the collection of window name, for each window name request the blank page[see 3.]. That will close each child window.

```js
function closeAllChildWindow() {
        var wins = localStorage.length
        for (var i = 1; i <= wins; i++) {
            var winName = localStorage.getItem("ChildWinName" + i.toString());
            if (winName != null) {
                window.open('/SomeSite/SomeApp/blankClose", "Home")', winName);
                localStorage.removeItem("ChildWinName" + i.toString())
            }
            else {
                if (localStorage.length > 0) wins++;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note** :
Instead of having multiple keys in local storage, JSON object can be used which has encapsulated string collection.

Comment: how come you answered your own questions? and both in the space of 1 minute so you planned doing that lol.

Comment: I had solution with me just wanted to share to the world. :)